# Why is vector of unique_ptr the prefered way to store pointers?

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

What I have readen say that a common approach to make a vector of pointer that own the pointers, of `MyObject` for example for simples uses, is `vector<unique_pointer<MyObject>>`.

But each time we access an element will call `unique_ptr::get()`. There is also a little overhead.

Why isn't vector of the pointer with "custom deleter", if such a thing exists (I don't have used allocators), more standard? That is, a smart vector instead of a vector of a smart pointer. It will eliminate the little overhead of using `unique_ptr::get()`.

Something like `vector<MyObject*, delete_on_destroy_allocator<MyObject>>` or `unique_vector<MyObject>`.

The vector would take the behaviour "delete pointer when destroy" instead of duplicate this behaviour in each unique_ptr , is there a reason, or is just the overhead neglegible ?

Comment: BTW, `get()` is in practice zero overhead as it most likely just does `return ptr;`

Comment: In reality there is no overhead. If you think there is, try measuring it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither a vector of `unique_ptr`'s nor a vector of plain pointers are the preferred way to store data. In your example: `std::vector<MyObject>` is usually just fine, and if you know the size at compile time, try `std::array<int>`.

If you absolutely need indirect references , you can also consider `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyObject>>`. Read about reference wrappers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Having said that... if you:

- Need to store your vector somewhere else than your actual data, or
- If `MyObject`s are very large / expensive to move, or
- If construction or destruction of `MyObject`s has real-world side-effects which you want to avoid;

and, additionally, you want your `MyObject` to be freed when it's no longer refered to from the vector is gone - the vector of unique pointers is relevant.

Now, pointers are just a plain and simple data type inherited from the C language; it doesn't have custom deleters or custom anything... but - `std::unique_ptr` [*does* support custom deleters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Also, it may be the case that you have more complex resource management needs for which it doesn't makes sense to have each element manage its own allocation and de-allocation - in which case as "smart" vector class may be relevant.

So: Different data structures fit different scenarios.

Comment: "*An std::vector of unique_ptr's is certainly not the preferred way to store integers*" That's not what he said; he said "common approche to make a **vector of pointer**"

Comment: @NicolBolas: S/he did say it in the question title... but I'll rephrase.

Comment: I don't see a version of the title that doesn't say "store pointers".

Comment: I've updated the text, the question was not specifically about int but about polymorphic objects more generally

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't vector of pointer with "custom deleter", if such a thing exists

Because such a thing *doesn't* exist and *cannot* exist.

The allocator supplied to a container exists to allocate memory for the container and (optionally) creates/destroys the objects in that container. A `vector<T*>` is a container of pointers; therefore, the allocator allocates memory for the pointer and (optionally) creates/destroys the pointers. It is not responsible for the *content* of the pointer: the object it points to. That is the domain of the user to provide and manage.

If an allocator takes responsibility for destroying the object being pointed to, then it must logically also have responsibility for *creating* the object being pointed to, yes? After all, if it didn't, and we copied such a `vector<T*, owning_allocator>`, each copy would expect to destroy the objects being pointed to. But since they're pointing to the same objects (copying a `vector<T>` copies the `T`s), you get a double destroy.

Therefore, if `owning_allocator::destruct` is going to delete the memory,  `owning_allocator::construct` *must* also create the object being pointed to.

So... what does this do:

```
vector<T*, owning_allocator> vec;
vec.push_back(new T());
```

See the problem? `allocator::construct` cannot decide when to create a `T` and when not to. It doesn't know if its being called because of a `vector` copy operation or because `push_back` is being called with a user-created `T*`. All it knows is that it is being called with a `T*` value (technically a reference to a `T*`, but that's irrelevant, since it will be called with such a reference in both cases).

Therefore, either it 1) allocates a new object (initialized via a copy from the pointer it is given), or 2) it copies the pointer value. And since it cannot detect which situation is in play, it must always pick the same option. If it does #1, then the above code is a memory leak, because the vector didn't store the `new T()`, and nobody else deleted it. If it does #2, then you can't copy such a vector (and the story for internal vector reallocation is equally hazy).

What you want is not possible.

A `vector<T>` is a container of `T`s, whatever `T` may be. It treats `T` as whatever it is; any *meaning* of this value is up to the user. And ownership semantics are part of that meaning.

`T*` has no ownership semantics, so `vector<T*>` *also* has no ownership semantics. `unique_ptr<T>` has ownership semantics, so `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` also has ownership semantics.

This is why Boost has `ptr_vector<T>`, which is *explicitly* a vector-style class that specifically contains pointers to `T`s. It has a slightly modified interface because of this; if you hand it a `T*`, it knows it is adopting the `T*` and will destroy it. If you hand it a `T`, then it allocates a new `T` and copies/moves the value into the newly allocated `T`. This is a different container, with a different interface, and different behavior; therefore, it merits a different *type* from `vector<T*>`.